# What's the deal with the stackoverflow360.com site?

Tags: support

I was doing a google search and a result came back with a URL for https://stackoverflow360.com/questions/tagged/.net+nuget?page=4&sort=newest&pagesize=15

Navigating to this site shows a site that is very similar to the normal SO site.

I did a look up on http://stackoverflow360.com.ipaddress.com/ but all the contact details are suppressed.

Is this some sort of mirror site, or just a rip off?

Comment: @TinyGiant Question here is whether it *is* a ripoff, which I'd admit I'm having a hard time answering.

Comment: @Undo:  It's *so* fishy though!  Something about it just seems...off...

Comment: Definitely @Makoto.`2400:cb00:2048:1::6818:6206` appears to be in Hong Kong, so we can probably say that this is a scraper. Did a darn good job of it, though, and I'm not sure what his motive is.

Comment: I'd bet... something... that it isn't real. The login page is a blank page and the attribution required link at the bottom links to http://blog.stackoverflow360.com/2009/06/attribution-required/

Comment: God, the topbar on that website is bigly awful. And it sticks to the top!  Terrible design.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a ripoff - more specifically, it looks like a proxy. They're probably phishing for logins, hijacking ad revenue, or some other form of nastiness.

That valid SSL cert threw me off at first, but it ends up being the key. Whoever is running this knows how to save money by not buying more certificates than necessary:

[image: all of this is legit]

Comment: Interesting. Looks like a UCC cert but I wasn't aware they did wildcards now

Comment: Good find. Normally it's pretty easy to see if its a rip-off once you go into some questions, but this was rather well done. Will you take care of reporting it to SO, or should I?

Comment: Hmmm... xvideo18, xvideotoday... encyclopediass... excuse me, I need to ... uh, I'll be busy... bbl.

Comment: I only noticed I was there when I clicked on an upvote... I wasn't logged in, and then almost entered my credentials there... This is not good to have around...